# How to unzip files bigger than 4GB?

Tags: redhat, compression

I'm using RHEL 5.6 and unzip-5.52-3.el5. I'm trying to unzip a big file, but I get the error:

```
unzip -o test.zip -d unzip/
error:  Zip file too big (greater than 4294959102 bytes)
Archive:  test.zip
warning [test.zip]:  4294967296 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
```

Is there another program that can work with large zip files or do I have to wait until unzip 6 comes to RHEL? (might be years!)

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally ended up rolling my own rpm's for unzip 6, they can be found here: http://www.noodles.net.nz/2011/02/15/unzip-6-for-rhel-5-6/

Comment: you can select your own answer as the one that solved the problem

Comment: I compiled the current unzip-6.0 from scratch - it didn't fix the problem.

Comment: rpm at http://www.noodles.net.nz/2011/02/15/unzip-6-for-rhel-5-6/ worked for me

Answer (score 50):

If you've got Java on the box, you can use

```
jar xf test.zip
```

Comment: saved me from having to bug the SAs to install unzip6. Thanks!

Comment: life saved. [ beer token ]

Comment: I had a 16+GB zip file downloaded from my wife's phone using AirDroid, and this trick saved me a lot of trouble!

Answer (score 6):

You can either use javas jar, or (in my opinion) even better: 7-zip. Most distros allow for it to be installed from repos, so you can use for example (on ubuntu):

```
sudo apt-get install p7zip-full
7z x huge.zip
```

Note how the command is **not** p7z or p7zip, but only **7z**. Also the x option has no preceding **-**. Best of luck!

Comment: This answer has already been given 6 years ago.

Comment: This method worked for me with a 16GB `zip` — I trust the `jar` method also works but did not try that. Thanks.

Comment: @GeraldSchneider This answer helped me regardless of when it was answered.

Answer (score 5):

I've found good success with 7-zip, it appears they have a fedora core build as well that might work for you, the downloads can be found at http://www.7-zip.org/download.html.  Failing the fedora one, you can download the source and/or binary and try that.

Comment: I played around with 7-zip (7z), but when extracting files from my zip it kept saying unrecognised format.

Comment: Check if 7z isn't an alias for 7zr. Try running 7za.

Comment: The package p7zip-full ships a command 7z, which accepts the x (extract) option. So in my case, using '7z x huge.zip' worked without issue.

Comment: 7z fails for me, says the file is corrupt. The most upvoted jar answer did work though

Answer (score -2):

I tried all the steps mentioned above to unzip the file, but failed miserably.

My last resort was to copy my zip file (11.1GB) into a hard drive and unzip it using 7 zip on Windows 8 OS.

Worked like a charm :D

Comment: That is not an answer to this question.

Comment: I tried in more ways than one to get it running on Linux... None of the solutions worked... So I'm giving a better alternative... Much more easier and hassle-free alternative..

Comment: Beyond 4 GB, linux is unable to unzip files... Windows I'm afraid has a much better mechanism to unzip huge zip files... So just giving out that info...

Comment: No it's not, silly.   Read above.  Just don't use `/bin/unzip`

Comment: `jar xf file.zip` or `7z x file.zip` and others are fine

Comment: jar xf file.zip worked for me, but 7z x file.zip failed (Ubuntu, 4.4GB file)